# How to rename or change the names of the network interface cards given by the hardware abstraction layer? (Ubuntu 14.04.3)

Tags: networking, bash, network-manager, nic, hal

I created a live system using Systemback in "computer A" and installed it with no problems in "computer B" but the only annoyance is that HAL gave my network interface cards the names `eth1` to the Wired Interface and `wlan2` to the Wireless Interface in "computer B". I have a lot of scripts and aliases hardcoded (BAD PRACTICE, I know).

Systemback created an exact copy of my configuration in "computer A" so this is why in "computer B" It couldn't hand out `eth0` and `wlan0` because these two names were already in use.

I know how to and can easily replace the problematic text with `sed` in all the scripts and aliases but i'd like to know how can I change these names given by HAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happened: when you did the original setup on System A, your machine reserved the names `eth0` and `wlan0` for the particular devices you had in that machine.

When you moved to System B, the new network devices were found, and (as you mention) renamed to not conflict with those earlier definitions of `eth0` and `wlan0`.

That original mapping of names is kept in:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

If you delete that file, your next boot will start up with no "reserved" names for those network devices in System A, and you'll get eth0 and wlan0 back.

If they're discovered in a different order (say, if you had two `ethX` devices in System B, and you expect them in a different order), you can edit the `NAME=` defintions in that file to suit your own naming requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited the file, did not delete it (I was scared :O) and made a backup just in case, rebooted and everything worked like a charm. Cheers! #MyFirstAnswer